# I need to display table header in my code

Tags: php, html-table, display

The code that i made display the header after each row in the table.
I want just one time the header appear on the top.Any help?

```
  print "<table border=1>\n"; 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
  $files_field= $row['filename'];
  $files_show= "Uploads/$files_field";
  $descriptionvalue= $row['title'];
print "<tr>";
print "<th>";
echo "header1";
print "</th>";
print "<th>";
echo "header2";
print "</th>";

print "</tr>";


print "<tr>\n"; 
print "\t<td>\n"; 

echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$descriptionvalue</font>";
print "</td>\n";
print "\t<td>\n"; 

echo "<div align=center><a href='".$files_show."' target='_blank'      title='CLICK TO OPEN'>$files_field</a></div>";
print "</td>\n";
print "</tr>\n"; 
} 
print "</table>\n";
```

Comment: where is loop? Please mention full code... Write header before your loop & in loop you have to mention loop data <tr>

Comment: fyi, from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font regarding `<font>`: "_This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it._"

Comment: Ok I added the loop then how to input the code so that the table has only one header on the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be adequate I think:

```
<?php
// print the beginning of the table, and the header
echo "<table border='1'>";

echo "<tr>";

echo "<th>";
echo "header1";
echo "</th>";

echo "<th>";
echo "header2";
echo "</th>";

echo "</tr>";
// than loop through the rows and print the rest of the table
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  $files_field = $row['filename'];
  $files_show  = "Uploads/{$files_field}";

  $descriptionvalue = $row['title'];

  echo "<tr>\n"; 
  echo "\t<td>\n"; 

  echo "<font face=arial size='4'/>$descriptionvalue</font>";

  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td>"; 

  echo "<div align=center><a href='{$files_show}' target='_blank' title='CLICK TO OPEN'>{$files_field}</a></div>";
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
```

Some additional notes / advises:

- don't mix `print` / `echo`: they are *almost* the same, it just causes confusion
- don't try to "prettify" the source with tabs and linebreaks: you are just bloating the output for no good reason, use the browsers inspector window instead
- forget the `mysql` driver, use `mysqli`: the former is so out of dae, that it is removed from the new versions of PHP (from 7.0), so your code will stop working if the platform is updated; the `mysqli` variant is a bit different in how you have to use it (an extra parameter mostly), but the results are in the same format, and it behaves very similarly if not identically to the old one, so you will not have to rewrite many things

Answer (score 1):

This program will:

- get a row from db
- print the header
- print the data
- get next row until the end

Sounds like you want to:

- print the header
- get a row from the db
- print the data
- get next row until the end